# Audio fingerprinting in javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, audio, web-audio-api, fingerprinting

I am trying to compare audio files at client side, I *will* not upload them on to the server, hence I want to get the fingerprint of the file even before uploading it to the server.

- Do we have a library which can be hosted on our website
- If No, Is it possible to do one , I am planning to

I have a song read from local system , I want to get its audio fingerprint so that I can compare with other audio file either on the server side or client side . I can send it to the server and get it done by methods already available in java or c# , but thats too much load to the bandwidth. So I wish to get the audio fingerprint at the client side itself using javascript .

Comment: There is an API called Echonest that (from the look of it) does "fingerprinting" but it's not a library - just an API. http://the.echonest.com/solutions/

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Taoist I guess its not free and can't be hosted in our server .

Comment: You should probably start by looking at simple waveform rendering scripts like this https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js . I don't know how to hack it to compare/contrast fingerprints but this library might be a good first start as something to play with.

Comment: @Taoist I will give it a try and update here. Thanks for the interest

Comment: @Oskar Eriksson read my reply to idbehold.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "fingerprint" but if you just want to get metadata information you can check out this library: https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader

Comment: I think he wants to compare and contrast waveform and spectral information of audio files and discern if it's the same file or if the similarities of this "fingerprint" are close enough to suggest so.The comparing and contrasting needs to happen in a manner where the actual audio file reside solely on the client (these files will not be uploaded to the server) but in a way where the data extracted from the "fingerprint" can be funneled to the server. If this is wrong @Skeptor please correct me.

Comment: @idbehold there might be audio without meta tags or same audio with different meta tag. So there is something called audio fingerprinting that can be done to verify the audio ...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [echoprint](https://github.com/spotify/echoprint-codegen) as it seems to be what your looking for.